# display field according to previous field input

Tags: php, html, forms

i am new to php,html i want to create a field label that will be changed according to the user choice in the previous field.
i.e first field user will choose his country then second field will appear with different label for example: if he chosed UAE label will be "Enter your ID:" if any other country label will be "Enter your Passport No."
any help will be appreciated

Comment: Are the labels on the same page? You'll have to use some JavaScript. What have you tried? Show some code that you've tried.

Comment: i created them in the same page but i don't have any idea how to do it.thats why i asked i hope you could help @matt

Comment: Start with a jQuery and JavaScript tutorial. At the very least, post the code that generates your page.

Comment: What have you tried? There are plenty of tutorials on how to do this. You can learn more about what types of questions to ask on stackoverflow here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you did not mention javascript or jquery, the most you can do is make two tables
one containing country id and country, and the other containing option_name and country id, (assuming you want to have same labels for some countries). 
Now you can easily put a Next Button which when clicked would fetch the option_name against the country id and then echo it as html on the page.
The way to avoid the "Next Button" part is to use jquery (methods like post() and get()) or javascript (the former is much cleaner and requires less code).

Answer (score 0):

try this one  you need javascript .its tested

```
<form method='POST' action='pageurl'>
<label for='field1'>Your name</label>
<input id='field1' name='field1' type='text' />

<label for='field2'>Status</label>
<select id='field2' name='field2'>
    <option>-select one-</option>
    <option value='Employee'>Employee</option>
    <option value='Retiree'>Retiree</option>
</select>
<br>
<label for='field3'>City you work in</label>
<input id='field3' name='field3' type='text' />
</form>
```

then use this javascript code

```
$('#field2').change(function() {
    var labels = {
        'Employee' : 'City you work in',
        'Retiree' : 'City you live in',
        '-select one-': 'Default value'
    }      
    $("label[for='field3']").html(labels[$(this).val()]);
});
```